# How to know the type of an object is checkbox in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to detect type of object is 'checkbox' or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
    // is checkbox
} else {
    // not checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check its *type* attribute.  Using JQuery:

```
if($('input').attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
   // do if checkbox
} else {
  // do if not checkbox
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(element).attr('type') == 'checkbox'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").whatever();
```